# Generic Vector to strong typed array

Tags: java, android, vector

I have method that returns me generic Vector with some data. How can I get type of this Vector childrens on runtime? I spend last day trying to find solution in Java documentation and google.
When I try do i.e.:

```
Vector<String> myVector = new Vector<String>();
//here I fill array with data
.......
// here I my code don't know now what is element type of 
// myVector and need to get it in some way
Class<?> baseClass = myVector.toArray().getClass().getComponentType();
```

Last line return me `Object`.

Comment: Is it the case that the `Vector` will not be empty?

Answer (score 0):

Generic parameter types like `<String>` exist only during compilation and will get a *type erasure*, so only `Object` remains.

Okay, one may take the most specialised common class:

```
public Class<?> commonComponentClass(Collection<?> collection) {
    Class<?> klazz = null;
    for (Object item : collection) {
        if (item == null)
            continue;
        Class<?> itemKlazz = item.getClass();
        if (klazz == null) {
            klazz = itemKlazz;
        } else {
            while (klazz != itemKlazz) {
                if (itemKlazz.isAssignableFrom(klazz)) {
                    klazz = itemKlazz;
                    break;
                } else if (klazz.isAssignableFrom(itemKlazz)) {
                    break;
                }
                if (itemKlazz != Object.class)
                    itemKlazz = itemKlazz.getSuperclass();
                if (klazz != Object.class)
                    klazz = klazz.getSuperclass();
            }
        }
    }
    if (klazz == null) {
        klazz = Object.class;
    }
    return klazz;
}
```